# Criando arquivo doc ou docx

Tags: java, android

Queria saber se existe alguma lib capaz de criar um arquivo doc ou docx direto de um app android. Já tentei usar apache poi, mas não dá certo. Estou usando o android studio. já tentei de várias maneiras mas não consigo, se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Olha cara eu dei uma pesquisada e também não achei nenhuma lib capaz de gerar arquivo .doc não cara, Mas tem outra forma de fazer mas dai você teria que ter contato a algum servidor php, Dai você enviaria as informações do seu app para uma pagina php que criaria um .doc e você pegava o retorno fazendo download e salvando diretamente no android. Espero ter ajudado, Caso você ache a forma de fazer isso diretamente pelo android poste aí para a galera que também tem a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Já viu esse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877532/how-to-create-docx-files-and-xlsx-files-on-android) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não vai encontrar nada muito mastigado.

## Manipulando diretamente o documento em XML

No entanto, dependendo da finalidade, se for algo simples como adicionar um pequeno texto num arquivo existente, isso pode ser feito modificando diretamente o XML.

O formato interno dos arquivos DOCX é basicamente um ZIP com outros arquivos dentro, sendo que o documento texto nada mais é do que um XML.

[Este artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx) (em Inglês) ensina a como explorar e manipular um documento dessa forma.

Com base nisso, basta definir quais informações você quer manipular, criar um arquivo modelo, observar o XML e criar uma rotina para automatizar a manipulação do mesmo.

## Usando uma biblioteca especializada

Se o que você precisa é mais complexo, por exemplo, gerar relatórios ou exportar documentos com vários elementos, uma solução é adquirir uma biblioteca como [Aspose.Words for Android](http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component.aspx), um produto especializado para esse tipo de operação e que pode prover o suporte necessário para suas necessidades.